# How to get G+ unique id in G+ sign up in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm integrating Google Plus in my app, i can access the basic details using:

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)
```

but I'm not getting the unique key of Google Plus as FBID in Facebook API integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html) it [should work like this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed_in_user):

```
  if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String personId = currentPerson.getId();
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much, thats "currentPerson.getId()" what i wanted.